# multiple tableview in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I tried this but getting an exception error at cellforrowatindexpath

Below is the exception I got.

Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:],     /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84

```
if(aTableView==specTable)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [specTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    return cell;

} 
else 
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [table2     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReviewCellIdentifier2];
}

return cell;
```

Comment: at least, please make the effort to provide a compilable example... And format your code! You don't properly use whitespaces, indentation, etc. It's hard to read what you write!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using 'CellIdentifier2' instead of 'ReviewCellIdentifier2'? Also, return cell should be inside the else statement, it is losing scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You never return `cell2`. At the end of this method, you always return `cell`, regardless of whether the sender table view was equal to the first or second one.
2. You don't create the cell as you do in the first part if in the second part (the `else` branch) the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` message returns `nil`.

All in all:

```
if (aTableView == specTable)
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [specTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; // you were also leaking memory here

    }

    return cell;

} 
else 
{    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [table2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
    if (cell2 == nil)
    {
        cell2 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    return cell2;
}

return nil; // just to make the compiler happy
```

Comment: May I know why is this memory leaking ?

Comment: If you don't use ARC you have to compensate the allocation with an autorelease.